# Contour Plot for least squares problem with discrete topology

Tags: tikz-pgf, contour

### Problem

There are many helpful examples on creating contour plots in LaTeX using `tikz` and `pgfplot`. Yet all the examples so far cover contour plots in the continuum. How would one make a contour plot in discrete space where we must sum over data points? That is, how does one plot a merit function for problems in $l_{2}$?

### Inputs specification

The inputs would be

1. mesh (`time`)
2. measurements (`counts`)
3. extremal point `(a,b) = (108,-0.008)`
4. plot range `($\Delta a$, $\Delta b$) = ( 15, 0.0025)`
5. contour values `(1000, 1200, ..., 3200)`

The first two items, the mesh and the measurement, are used to define the merit function. The last three items control the appearance of the plot. The extremal point, the least squares solution, will be computed in another application and centers the plot. The plot range is expressed as a half-window size. The final item contains the contour values to display.

### Output

The output is a plot of the merit function with contours at given values centered on the least squares solution point.

### Example problem

A simple example with radioactive decay using Mathematica follows. The trial function is $y(t) = a \exp ( b t)$ where $t$ is the time in seconds and $y$ are the decays at that time.

#### Define mesh, measurements

[image]

#### Define the merit function, find minimum

[image]

#### Contour plot of the merit function

[image]

Comment: What is your question?  Do you want to draw level curves with `TikZ`?  I don't understand the title of your question; what the discrete topology has to do with your example?

Comment: @DanielN: In the continuum we would minimize the integral of the squares of functions. In the discrete topology we minimize the sum of the squares of samples of functions. The example functions show in In[591] details the discrete summation over two lists, time and counts.